Date Timer Picker - Timezone offset suppression
I had some huge problems with Kendo UI Date(Time)Picker in a Kendo Form.
(In Kendo Grid Popup, the Date(Time)Picker behaves different and does not add timezone offsets)
The problem was, that client side it always added a local timezone offset which led to "incorrect" dates in the database.
For example, i set the date to 2000/1/1 and in the database i would get the utc date 1999/12/31T22:00:00 with a two hour offset
Client side it displayed the date correct, but following processes in sql etc did not work any longer (eg invoice date), for obvious reasons

The problem itself only showed up sometimes and as I found out it was fairly easy to work around it.
The model which is bound to the view allows ISO dates "yyyy-MM-dd..." and js Dates
If the model loads data from the database it is filled with iso dates, if you set a model value with a datepicker, it sets a js date
If you catch the json date and write it as an iso date to the model in the change event (datepicker/form), it will not do any timezone offset (because there is none)
I used luxon, because it was just way more intuitive than js date, but you just have to diff the local timezone offset to utc and then convert it to a iso date string
function dtp_suppressOffset(jsdateTime) {
    return luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(jsdateTime).toISODate({ includeOffset: false })
}

Took me some time and it really made me mad, and i did not found good solutions, so here is mine workaround for whoever needs it
